# Why do 2 excel (2003) files that are exactly the same have different file size?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003

I have two excel files that are exactly the same (in terms of the content of the file) but differ by quite a margin on file size. One file is 37.5 KB while the other is 56 KB. The only difference I can see is the file names. I don't know why there is such a big difference. Is there some sort of history or something that is stored with the file that is not visible to the user? If so, how would you delete this?

Comment: Are your files on the same filesystem? If they are on different filesystems that don't have the same block size, that might be the reason.

Answer (score 1):

There may be an excess of blank rows or columns in the larger file. If this is the case, the larger file will have a much lager scroll-able area and much smaller scroll bars (along the right and bottom edges of the window).

To delete extra columns, highlight the first blank column, hold ctrl + shift, and press the right arrow key to select them all. Right click the highlighted columns and select "Delete" from the context menu. Next, select the first blank row, hold ctrl + shift, press the down arrow key and delete the extra row.

Now save the document. Once saved, the scroll bars should return to the appropriate size, the scrollable area should now include only the area of the spreadsheet that contains data, and the size of the file should decrease.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Office applications keep all kinds of junk besides the current contents of the document. You can clean up the file with the [Remove Hidden Data Add-in](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834427).

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new, empty .xls file, copy the data you want from a larger file, and paste it into the new one.

Comment: It's not about the data, I wanted to know why there was such a big difference in file size and what was causing it. The formatting of both spreadsheets is exactly the same.

Comment: well, as others have said, Excel does not optimize itself continuously for file size, as you're seeing.  There's more to an .xls file than data and formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Excel files can become 'fragmented' with constant editing.  If you want to reduce the file size to a minimum, look at the following:

http://www.ehow.com/how_2252595_reduce-size-excel-files.html

Answer (score 0):

Excel does have a "Track Changes" feature under Tools/Track Changes on the menu bar; although it only keeps change records for a default of 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

I'have just made the same observation, that 2 Excel files with the same content differ in file size: 670 KB and 715 KB.

There is no difference in content nor in formatting.

By right-clicking it and looking into Properties -> Details, there were different values for (translated from German, don't know whether the naming is exact for English Version):
 - Last save by (no value in file with less size)
 - Scaling (no value in file with less size)
 - Links to be updated (no value in file with less size)

Cool regards!

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. When you have a little reputation, you will be able to comment on other people's posts.